# Open event on jqueryUI works intermittently

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I have a jqueryUI dialog box which makes a request to another page and loads the content in the dialog box.

```
jQuery("#someDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    open: function() {
        jQuery(this).load('myurl?type=something');
    }
});​
```

However, this code at times just opens the dialog box and the loaded content isn't shown in the dialog box. I suspect this is because of the asynchronous code inside the open event.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: don't see any issues here http://jsfiddle.net/paaH3/... Is your `#someDialog` element static?  are there more than one of those elements?  How are you opening the dialog?

Comment: `#someDialog` element is static. the `myurl` has a jqGrid in it which makes a request to a URL to load its data. So, when every thing is smooth then I see two calls being made when opening the dialog 1) to `myurl` and 2) to 'urltoloadGridData`. However, when nothing loads in the modalbox then I only see the first call, not the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I typically load the content into a variable div, then put it's html as the text for the dialogbox when opening it.

```
$('#popupWindow').load('whatever?type=something', function () {

    // using the callback function on .load() we can ensure
    // the content is always loaded before opening the dialog also 

    var _dialogBox = $('<div id="dialogBox" />');

    // put the html inside of the dialog
    _dialogBox.html( $('#popupWindow').html() );


    _dialogBox.dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true
    });​

    _dialogBox.dialog('open');
});
```

Comment: hmm, very nice trick. In my instance, however, doing this is making the popup open in a new pager rather than be a modalbox.

Comment: Forgot to mention in this case the div #popupWindow is already in the html of the page and `display:none;`. That might be why it's opening in a new page

Comment: I don't see `text` as one of the methods for jQueryUI: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Sorry I forgot I had a custom dialog function I made to add to Dialog! Updated the code. Basically you need to create the div on the fly add the html there.